# Passing multiselect selected items into SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, multi-select

I can't seem to find a good example of this online.  What I want to do is pass all of the values of a multiselect listbox into a SQL stored procedure to write them to a table.

I know that if I want to pass one selected value to SQL I would do this:

**C#:**

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_RegisterUser", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPreferences", SqlDbType.Char).Value = MatchPrefs.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.Char).Value = UserName.Text;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**SQL:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RegisterUser]
    @UserPreferences varchar(max),
    @UserName varchar(25)

AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tmpUserMatch (
    UserID,
    MatchField,
    MatchValue

    )
VALUES (
    (SELECT Top 1 UserID FROM tmpUsers WHERE UserName = @UserName),
    'MatchPreferences',
    @UserPreferences
    )

END
```

But how would I do this if MatchPrefs is a multiselect?

**EDIT**

I have the C# part down, by replacing:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPreferences", SqlDbType.Char).Value = MatchPrefs.SelectedValue;
```

with:

```
var selectedInterests = MatchPrefs.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected).Select(item => item.Value).ToList();
string strInterests = String.Join(",", selectedInterests).TrimEnd();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPreferences", SqlDbType.Char).Value = strInterests;
```

and on the SQL end I have a function that will create a table-valued parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@UserPreferences)
```

Just need some help completing the SQL side with the 2 additional fields I need to include; UserID and MatchField.

Comment: You want to look into structured parameters in ADO.NET and the equivalent table valued params in SQL Server SPs. Basically it allows you to push a strong typed list of objects to SQL Server SPs/queries. Lots of examples on here and on the Internet.

Comment: So how would that be done with the 2 additional fields I need to add to the SQL table (UserID and MatchField)?

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid the sp_ prefix as that is reserved by microsoft and can cause some performance issues. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix Or event better, just drop the prefix entirely.

Comment: I'd pass the parameter as XML. You can create this within your application in many different ways and within SQL it's fairly easy to deal with XML. This gives you best flexibility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't prefix procs with `sp_` (this hurts performance as it causes SQL Server to look in the `[master]` DB first)
2. Use `SqlDbType.VarChar`
3. Specify the max length  (`-1` is for `MAX`, but I highly doubt you need even 8000 characters)
4. Input param definition for `@UserPreferences` should have matching max length (again, no reason to use `MAX`)
5. Don't pass in `@UserName` just so you can look it up. Pass in `@UserID` instead. Look it up beforehand and store it in the Session or ViewState if you use it on several pages, else get it when you load the initial page.
6. Why do you instantiate a `DataAdapter` ?
7. Your SQL split function doesn't create a Table-Valued Parameter. It simply returns a result set.

```
INSERT INTO SchemaName.tmpUserMatch (
    UserID,
    MatchField,
    MatchValue
)
SELECT
    @UserID,
    'MatchPreferences',
    csv.SplitVal
 FROM dbo.SplitCSV(@UserPreferences) csv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the list from multiselect:

```
    private string GetList(ListItemCollection list)
    {
        string separadosporcoma = "";

        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in list)
                separadosporcoma += item.Value + ",";
            separadosporcoma = separadosporcoma.TrimEnd(',');
        }
        return separadosporcoma;
    }
```

In SQL Server I use this table-valued function:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fn_ParseCSVString]
(
@CSVString  varchar(8000) ,
@Delimiter  varchar(10)
)
returns @tbl table (s varchar(1000))
as
begin
declare @i int ,
    @j int
    select  @i = 1
    while @i <= len(@CSVString)
    begin
        select  @j = charindex(@Delimiter, @CSVString, @i)
        if @j = 0
        begin
            select  @j = len(@CSVString) + 1
        end
        insert  @tbl select substring(@CSVString, @i, @j - @i)
        select  @i = @j + len(@Delimiter)
    end
    return
end
```

And in my stored procedure in the where clause I call to the sql function like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetValuesWithList] 
@MyList AS VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT values
FROM MyTable
WHERE items in (SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_ParseCSVString(@MyList, ',') fn_ParseCSVString)))
```

I think this might help you.